Are there any non-trivial subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy trichotomy and additive closure?
Consider any subset $\mathbb{P}\subset\mathbb{R}.$
Trichotomy says that if $x\in\mathbb{R},$ then exactly one of the following holds-
$$x\in\mathbb{P}$$
$$-x\in\mathbb{P}$$
$$x=0$$
Additive closure says that if $x,y\in\mathbb{P},$ then $x+y\in\mathbb{P}.$
My question below is inspired by this question and also Exercise $1$ page $17$ from Bert Mendelson's Introduction to Topology, which asks that if $1\in \mathbb{P},\ \mathbb{P}$ is closed under addition, and $\mathbb{P}$ satisfies trichotomy, then $Q:=\{(a,b):(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R} \text{ and } a-b\in \mathbb{P}\},$ then prove that $Q$ is a transitive relation. The proof is quite straightforward, and doesn't require one to actually investigate subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy trichotomy and additive closure. However, this does not mean I cannot pose the following question:

Is it possible to construct a subset $\mathbb{P}\subset\mathbb{R}$ that
satisfies trichotomy and additive closure, other than $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x>0\}$ and $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x<0\}$?

I imagine we get some contradiction like in the linked question, but I don't see how to use the same line of logic.

What about $\Bbb P={x\in\Bbb R\mid x>0}$?

@JoséCarlosSantos True. I amended the question accordingly.

The choiceless version of this question might make a good MO-post, FWIW.

At least assuming the axiom of choice, there are lots of these. Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be a set of the prescribed type (say, $X=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$) and let $\pi$ be any automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space (of which there are continuum many). Then $\pi[X]$ is again a set of the prescribed type. This is because trichotomy and additive closure are each expressible in terms of the $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space structure, and so are preserved by automorphisms of that structure.
Actually all we really need is the $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure, but it's easier to think about vector spaces and doesn't cost us anything here.

What if we don't assume the axiom of choice? For example, it's consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there are no nonlinear solutions to Cauchy's functional equation, so "Every trichotomous and additively closed set is one of $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ or $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$" is prima facie plausibly consistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$ as well.
The standard strategy here would be to show that any nontrivial trichotomous additively-closed set would have some "wildness" property - e.g. be non measurable, or lack the property of Baire, or similar. At a glance I don't see such an argument, though. The only possibly-useful facts I see are that if $X$ is a nontrivial set of the prescribed type, then

$X$ is both dense and codense in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ (and $\mathbb{R}_{<0}$), and

for each 1-dimensional subspace $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$ (over $\mathbb{Q}$), either $S\cap X=S_{>0}$ or $S\cap X=S_{<0}$.


